# Losing starting vertex in search result

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

I have graph, where i am trying to find certain vertex's from given vertex, but in the search result I am not getting the starting vertex. Below is the query I am trying which loose the starting vertex.

```
g.V().has("orgId", 102)
.repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath())
.until(hasLabel("ORG"));
```

If I use emit() after has() function it prints all the the vertex's coming in the path, which is not required. I only need the ending vertex based on until condition.
We can try and execute here https://gremlify.com/w6o0d8htpt/8

Where as if we go for path(), it gives the starting vertex in the result, but we do not need path here. I am only looking for ending vertex.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you want to return. You mention wanting the starting vertex, but then you say you don't want the whole path. So, do you want just the starting vertex and all the places you ended up at without the full path in between?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence yes you are correct I need the vertex from where I started, and all the vertex where we ended up.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The answer below from @HadoopMarc should hopefully give you what you need then. If for any reason that is not sufficient please add another comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The union() step should do fine here:

```
g.V().has("orgId", 102).union(
    __.identity(),
    __.repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath())
       .until(hasLabel("ORG"))
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @HadoopMarc, it gives the desired result